# Example of a non-abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So we are given that $G$ must be a non-abelian group.  We are also given that $T_G = \{ x \in G | x^n = 1$ for some $n \geq 1 \} $.

I need to find an example of a non-abelian group $G$, such that $T_G$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

I've tried $D_8$ and $Q_8$, but in each of those cases $T_G = G$.  And $G$ is certainly a subgroup of itself.  So, those two groups don't work.

I was going to try matrices next.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You're going to have a hard time finding finite $G$ for which $T_G\ne G$.

Comment: Try matrices. $2 \times 2$ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 8):

A very simple example: let G be the group of permutations of $\mathbf Z$. Denote by $s$ the ‘symmetry’  $x\mapsto -x$ and $t$ be the ‘translation’ $x\mapsto x+1$. $s$ is of order 2, but $t$ has infinite order – indeed, $t^k$ is simply $x\mapsto x+k$. Now, it's easy to check $s\circ t$ has order 2 like $s$, but $s\circ(s\circ t)=t$ has infinite order.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the infinite dihedral group, consisting of all transformations of the real line of either of the two types: $x\mapsto n+x$ and $x\mapsto n-x$. Here, the “$n$”s are to be integers. The elements of the second type are involutions, i.e. $f\circ f=$ identity, but the composition of any two is of the first type.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product#Construction) $G=\mathbb Z_2*\mathbb Z_2=\{e,a\}*\{e,b\}$. Then $T_G=\{e,a,b\}$, which is not a subgroup of $G$.